bestmove from 'bestmove' in SF doesn't match bestmove from continuation when run from within another program
I've accidentally come across a very peculiar behavior whereby bestmove from 'bestmove' in SF16 doesn't match bestmove from continuation when run from within a Java program. E.g. when the following position r1bqk1nr/p2p1ppp/2p5/1pb5/2BpP3/2P5/PP1P1PPP/RNBQ1RK1 w - - 0 1 is analyzed directly in SF, the bestmove c4f7 is given by both the bestmove and continuation (in the example below, starting at depth 5):
go depth 15

info depth 1 seldepth 5 multipv 1 score cp 33 nodes 45 nps 22500 hashfull 0 tbhits 0 time 2 pv c4b3
info depth 2 seldepth 3 multipv 1 score cp 54 nodes 85 nps 28333 hashfull 0 tbhits 0 time 3 pv c4e2
info depth 3 seldepth 3 multipv 1 score cp 57 nodes 136 nps 45333 hashfull 0 tbhits 0 time 3 pv c4d3
info depth 4 seldepth 3 multipv 1 score cp 84 nodes 171 nps 57000 hashfull 0 tbhits 0 time 3 pv c4d3
info depth 5 seldepth 5 multipv 1 score cp 187 nodes 267 nps 89000 hashfull 0 tbhits 0 time 3 pv c4f7 e8f7
info depth 6 seldepth 6 multipv 1 score cp 266 nodes 427 nps 106750 hashfull 0 tbhits 0 time 4 pv c4f7 e8e7 f7g8
info depth 7 seldepth 7 multipv 1 score cp 259 nodes 633 nps 126600 hashfull 0 tbhits 0 time 5 pv c4f7 e8f7 d1h5 g7g6 h5c5 d4d3
info depth 8 seldepth 7 multipv 1 score cp 259 nodes 801 nps 133500 hashfull 0 tbhits 0 time 6 pv c4f7 e8f7 d1h5 g7g6 h5c5 d4d3
info depth 9 seldepth 9 multipv 1 score cp 237 nodes 1187 nps 169571 hashfull 0 tbhits 0 time 7 pv c4f7 e8f7 d1h5 g7g6 h5c5 d4d3 c5e3
info depth 10 seldepth 10 multipv 1 score cp 277 nodes 2883 nps 262090 hashfull 1 tbhits 0 time 11 pv c4f7 e8f7 d1h5 g7g6 h5c5 d4d3 c5e3
info depth 11 seldepth 12 multipv 1 score cp 288 nodes 4981 nps 311312 hashfull 2 tbhits 0 time 16 pv c4f7 e8f8 f7b3 d4d3 d1f3 g8f6 f3d3
info depth 12 seldepth 15 multipv 1 score cp 255 nodes 8817 nps 326555 hashfull 4 tbhits 0 time 27 pv c4f7 e8f7 d1h5 g7g6 h5c5 d4d3 c5d4 g8f6 e4e5 f6h5 d4d3
info depth 13 seldepth 16 multipv 1 score cp 267 nodes 11008 nps 355096 hashfull 4 tbhits 0 time 31 pv c4f7 e8f7 d1h5 g7g6 h5c5 d4d3 c5d4 g8f6 e4e5 f6h5 d4d3 h8f8
info depth 14 seldepth 19 multipv 1 score cp 277 nodes 17812 nps 371083 hashfull 7 tbhits 0 time 48 pv c4f7 e8f7 d1h5 g7g6 h5c5 d4d3 c5e3 g8f6 e3d3 h8e8 f2f3 d8b6 d3e3 b6e3 d2e3 d7d6
info depth 15 seldepth 21 multipv 1 score cp 276 nodes 30248 nps 408756 hashfull 12 tbhits 0 time 74 pv c4f7 e8f7 d1h5 g7g6 h5c5 d4d3 c5e3 g8f6 e4e5 f6h5 e3d3 h8f8 d3e3 f7g8 d2d4 h5f4
bestmove c4f7 ponder e8f7

However, if the same position is analyzed in SF running with that Java program, the bestmove from bestmove (i.e. c4e2) doesn't match bestmove from continuation (i.e. c4f7). From what I observed so far, in case of such discrepancies, the "bestmove" version is always weaker than the continuation version:
info depth 1 seldepth 5 multipv 1 score cp 33 nodes 235 nps 235000 hashfull 0 tbhits 0 time 1 pv c4b3
info depth 2 seldepth 5 multipv 1 score cp 98 nodes 449 nps 224500 hashfull 0 tbhits 0 time 2 pv c4f7 e8f7 d1h5 g7g6
info depth 3 seldepth 6 multipv 1 score cp 112 nodes 740 nps 370000 hashfull 0 tbhits 0 time 2 pv c4f7 e8f7
info depth 4 seldepth 5 multipv 1 score cp 155 nodes 1169 nps 389666 hashfull 0 tbhits 0 time 3 pv d1h5
info depth 5 seldepth 7 multipv 1 score cp 177 nodes 2231 nps 371833 hashfull 0 tbhits 0 time 6 pv c4f7 e8f7 d1h5 g7g6
info depth 6 seldepth 10 multipv 1 score cp 225 nodes 4463 nps 371916 hashfull 1 tbhits 0 time 12 pv c4f7 e8f8 f7b3 d4d3 d1f3 d8f6
info depth 7 seldepth 10 multipv 1 score cp 250 nodes 7451 nps 392157 hashfull 2 tbhits 0 time 19 pv c4f7 e8f7 d1h5 g7g6 h5c5 d4d3
info depth 8 seldepth 13 multipv 1 score cp 235 nodes 13385 nps 418281 hashfull 5 tbhits 0 time 32 pv c4f7 e8f7 d1h5 g7g6 h5c5 d4d3 a2a4 g8f6 a4b5 f6e4
info depth 9 seldepth 12 multipv 1 score cp 246 nodes 22775 nps 421759 hashfull 11 tbhits 0 time 54 pv c4f7 e8f7 d1h5 g7g6 h5c5 d4d3 c5e3
info depth 10 seldepth 12 multipv 1 score cp 262 nodes 38658 nps 415677 hashfull 14 tbhits 0 time 93 pv c4f7 e8f7 d1h5 g7g6 h5c5 d4d3 c5e3 g8f6 e3d3 h8e8
info depth 11 seldepth 17 multipv 1 score cp 261 nodes 57352 nps 437801 hashfull 20 tbhits 0 time 131 pv c4f7 e8f7 d1h5 g7g6 h5c5 d4d3 a2a4 g8f6 a4b5 h8e8 b5c6 e8e4
info depth 12 seldepth 16 multipv 1 score cp 249 nodes 112274 nps 445531 hashfull 39 tbhits 0 time 252 pv c4f7 e8f7 d1h5 g7g6 h5c5 d4d3 c5d4 g8f6 e4e5 f6d5 d4d3
info depth 13 seldepth 16 multipv 1 score cp 258 nodes 193323 nps 446473 hashfull 70 tbhits 0 time 433 pv c4f7 e8f7 d1h5 g7g6 h5c5 d4d3 a2a4 b5a4 c5c4 d7d5 c4d3 g8f6 e4e5
info depth 14 seldepth 19 multipv 1 score cp 308 nodes 270985 nps 452395 hashfull 101 tbhits 0 time 599 pv c4f7 e8f8 f7b3 a7a5 a2a4 d4d3 a4b5 d7d5
info depth 15 seldepth 19 multipv 1 score cp 274 nodes 391071 nps 482208 hashfull 142 tbhits 0 time 811 pv c4f7 e8f7 d1h5 g7g6 h5c5 d4d3 c5d4 g8f6 e4e5 f6d5 d4d3 d7d6 d3f3 f7g7 d2d4 h8e8
bestmove c4e2 ponder a7a6

Also, another issue with the last listing is that often times the depth seems out of sync e.g. at depth 2, it shows 4 moves and then at depth 4 it shows 1 move.
I thought it could have related to the application server multithreaded environment in which SF being executed, but extracting and executing the code in question in a single threaded program (i.e. unit test) didn't help.
Wondering if anyone experienced something similar and found a solution for it?

